# Sending base64 image with ajax and form data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image, base64

My client wants to capture form data and signature (using [signaturePad](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad)), I have created a solution with ajax but I can`t make both things to work together.

If I send image data as this:

```
var image = signaturePad.toDataURL();
$.ajax({
        url: './test1.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { imageData: image }
    })
```

This results ok and I can save the image later. (only sending image data, not form data)

But when I try to send image and form data as this:

```
var image = signaturePad.toDataURL();
data = $('#form').serialize() + '&imageData=' + image;
$.ajax({
        url: './test1.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data
    })
```

The image is saved but I can't open it later, I think the way for sending this is causing some error.

If I output to the console the imageData variable, the results of the first experiment is a block of text, for the second experiment the output is a block of text but different, it has new line characters like.

The best solution will be using the second experiment because my form has array like inputs and the logic is written and working ok, but the image is corrupted for some unknown reason to me. Any help appreciated.

EDIT: the image is a base64 encoded png.

Comment: Have you checked what the GET-Variables deliver? Probably you need to push "image" in the "data"-Array to send it as POST.

Comment: I'm checking them at the page that process the ajax request as POST, and they deliver different results

Comment: Whats the Output on the other End in base64?

Comment: @Bernhard your first answer solved the problem, I first serialize the form to data variable and then push the base64 image data to that array as an object. I'll post the solution in a minute, thank you.

Comment: Great to read this! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to use serializeArray() at the form and then push the 'imageData' (base64 image) to the array as an object:

```
//base 64 image
var image = signaturePad.toDataURL();

//form data serialized
data = $('#form').serializeArray();

//create and push imageData to array as object
b={ name: 'imageData', value: image };
data.push(b); 

//send POST request
$.ajax({
    url: './test1.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data
})
```

Now the image is created and send over post with no problems!